# Serilog Timing Rollup advice or ideas

Tags: stopwatch, serilog

I'm currently instrumenting an application which Serilog and monitoring some performance using the  Timing extra which in turn is using the loggly sink.

I love the insight I'm getting but I'm looking for a way to easily rollup or separate out different timings.

At the moment I have a timing like so:

```
using (_logger.BeginTimedOperation("Processing Sync Event"))
{
    MethodA();
    MethodB();
}

void MethodA()
{
    using(_logger.BeginTimedOperation("Processing MethodA"))
    {
    }
}

void MethodB()
{
    using(_logger.BeginTimedOperation("Processing MethodB"))
    {
    }
}
```

I thought about maybe using the identifier in someway to relate them together or make it easy to exclude child / parent depending on what I'm looking at in loggly. Of course I can simply exclude the TimedOperationDescription but I was wondering if anyone else had come up with a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
using (LogContext.PushProperty("Operation", id))
using (_logger.BeginTimedOperation("Processing sync event", identifier: id.ToString())
{
    MethodA();
    MethodB();
}
```

This relies on enabling `LogContext` like so:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    ...
```

`LogContext` has the advantage of carrying through to other log statements implicitly. If you'd rather avoid it and use explicit logger instances you can try:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var opLog = _logger.ForContext("Operation", id);
using (opLog.BeginTimedOperation("Processing sync event")
{
    MethodA(opLog);
    MethodB(opLog);
}
```

I.e. the contextual/op-specific log can be passed around.

Comment: Cool - That would definitely let me group them together so thanks for that. I was demoing the work I've done to my team today and I got talking about how I could mark the 'outside' one with some sort of property which would allow you filter it out of number to stop the number being double counted in a rollup e.g. Outside number + both the inside numbers. I think I'll pull the source for timings and have a look.